# Getting the loop index in an eco template

Tags: coffeescript, eco

Is it possible to get the current loop index using the eco template engine?

For example in Jinja2 you can do

```
{% for var in array %}
    {{ loop.index0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

If not is there a more idiomatic way of getting at the index?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [CoffeeScript website](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
# Fine five course dining.
courses = ['greens', 'caviar', 'truffles', 'roast', 'cake']
menu i + 1, dish for dish, i in courses
```

Could also be written as

```
courses = ['greens', 'caviar', 'truffles', 'roast', 'cake']
for dish, i in courses
  menu i + 1, dish
```

For the eco template, something like this should do it:

```
<% for val, idx in @varName: %>
<span>The index is <%= idx %> and value is <%= val %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Right but how would you do that in the context of an eco template.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just using the CoffeeScript for (but take care of the extra `:`):

```
<% for thing, i in @things: %>
  <%= i %>: <%= thing %>
<% end %>
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8J8ff/).

Comment: @Puce it [seems to be necessary](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco#a-note-about-whitespace). Are you using a different Eco version? When removing the colon from the jsFiddle example linked on the answer an error is raised: `Error: Parse error on line 3: unexpected dedent`.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I am not using the same template engine.